# power shell command not returning System model

Tags: powershell-5.0

I have the following power shell cmd and I would like to get it to return the model # of the PC it is run on.
I am not a programmer, I am simply trying to earn enough power shell to make my work life a bit easier.

When I run the below command the System Model field is blank?

Can anyone correct this?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select-Object Manufacturer, "System Model", SMBIOSBIOSVersion, SerialNumber, @{Name="AssetTag"; Expression={(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_SystemEnclosure" | select-object -ExpandProperty SMBIOSAssetTag)}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When I run the below command the System Model field is blank?

> ```
> Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select-Object Manufacturer, "System Model", SMBIOSBIOSVersion, SerialNumber, @{Name="AssetTag"; Expression={(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_SystemEnclosure" | select-object -ExpandProperty SMBIOSAssetTag)}}
> ```

There is no `System Model` property in `win32_bios`:

```
> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -Property *


Status                : OK
Name                  : BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03
Caption               : BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03
SMBIOSPresent         : True
Description           : BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03
InstallDate           :
BuildNumber           :
CodeSet               :
IdentificationCode    :
LanguageEdition       :
Manufacturer          : American Megatrends Inc.
OtherTargetOS         :
SerialNumber          : 27546064-5001600
SoftwareElementID     : BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03
SoftwareElementState  : 3
TargetOperatingSystem : 0
Version               : Sony - 20110905
PrimaryBIOS           : True
BiosCharacteristics   : {7, 9, 11, 12…}
BIOSVersion           : {Sony - 20110905, BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03, BIOS Date: 09/05/11 11:20:58 Ver: 04.06.03}
CurrentLanguage       :
InstallableLanguages  :
ListOfLanguages       :
ReleaseDate           : 05/09/2011 01:00:00
SMBIOSBIOSVersion     : R1190V3
SMBIOSMajorVersion    : 2
SMBIOSMinorVersion    : 7
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/cimv2:Win32_BIOS
CimInstanceProperties : {Caption, Description, InstallDate, Name…}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

Note: The above output is from version 7.2.8

---

#### Futher Rewading:

- [Win32_BIOS - powershell.one](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_bios)
- [Win32_BIOS class - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-bios)

Comment: Well - there is my mistake then tyvm. I notice when I run systeminfo the model is there. Is there anyway I can incorporate that command and filter just the model into my results or do you think I should be doing this a different way? OR, is there no easy way to get it done and I need to do more reading?

Comment: @user1800001 - Is it an OEM machine by chance?

Comment: Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios | get-member

Comment: It IS an OEM machine - they all are at my corp.

Comment: @user1800001 - I am confused by your last statement in that case.  What did you mean by "there is my mistake then .."

Answer (score 1):

There is no "System Model" property in WMI **Win32_BIOS** class.

To get computer model information use **Win32_ComputerSystem** that has "Model" property and preferably use Get-CimInstance instead of Get-WmiObject

[Win32_ComputerSystem class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem)

Comment: What I would like to get info about is, Make, Model, SN, Asset tag (My corp enters asset tags into the BIOS before distribution. Ideally the output would be similar to this with the model# field not blank.                                                                                                          Manufacturer      : LENOVO
System Model      :
SMBIOSBIOSVersion : N2XET38W (1.28 )
SerialNumber      : PF2JCWS4
AssetTag          : 9365830

Comment: Also, obviously I need to do more reading. Is there a way to accept this question as resolved?

Comment: tyvm for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Get-ComputerInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet to retrieve the information youare looking for.

> Gets a consolidated object of system and operating system properties.

```ps
Get-ComputerInfo | Select Csmodel, BiosSerialNumber, BiosSMBIOSBIOSVersion, CsManufacturer
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your answer but it produced this:                                                                           PS C:\Users\TAF1371> Get-ComputerInfo | Select Csmodel, BiosSerialNumber, BiosSMBIOSBIOSVersion, CsManufacturer

CsModel    BiosSerialNumber BiosSMBIOSBIOSVersion CsManufacturer

---

20S7S3E009                  N2XET38W (1.28 )      LENOVO                                                            no asset tag, no serial number. I might need a script to do this as doing it in one simple command seems to be beyond the ability of PowerShell and it is not worth it to me to learn that much PowerShell scripting at this point in my career. TY all very much but this question is over.                                                                                                                         If I could use systeminfo and filter out what i do not want that would be fine but it seems that's impossible in PowerShell also. Cheers all.